# Pegar dados json imprimir em tempo real

Tags: php, ajax, json

Ola amigos boa noite !

Estou com esse código funcionando perfeitamente so preciso que ele imprima a variável tipo a cada 5 segundos me falaram que tinha que fazer isso com ajax  mais nao sei como fazer isso !

> json

```
[ {"latitude": "-3.3462, -60.67900"}]
```

> php

```html
<?php
    // ler o json
    $file = file_get_contents('json.php');    

  
    $decode = json_decode($file, true);

    
    $ultimo = end($decode);

  ?>

<?php $variavel = $ultimo['latitude'];?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sim, dá pra resolver com *Ajax* / **jQuery**:

**Página principal (*index.php*):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="DivSaida">
        <!-- VALOR DA VARIÁVEL SERÁ MOSTRADO AQUI -->
        <?php require_once("minhapagina.php"); ?>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        minhaUrl = "minhapagina.php"; // CAMINHO DA PÁGINA COM O ECHO

        setInterval(function(){

            $.ajax({
                url: minhaUrl,
                success: function( response ) {
                    $('#DivSaida').html( response );
                }
            });

        }, 5000); // TEMPO PARA ATUALIZAR EM MS (milissegundos)

    });
</script>
</html>
```

**Página com o `echo` da variável (*minhapagina.php*):**

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents('json.php');
$decode = json_decode($file, true);
$ultimo = end($decode);
$variavel = $ultimo['latitude'];
echo $variavel; //MOSTRA EXATAMENTE ESSE VALOR NA PÁGINA PRINCIPAL

?>
```

Não mudei a saída da sua *variável*, apenas dei um `echo`!
Deixei alguns comentários no código, aos quais achei interessante você alterar.

Comment: Desculpa mais coloquei aqui nao funcionou o que sera que estou errando

Comment: Fiz uma correção na **página principal**. Eu desenvolvi dentro do meu próprio projeto e ao postar, coloquei `scr` ao invés do `src` na importação do *jQuery*. Agora deve funcionar!

Comment: Podemos iniciar um chat

Comment: Preciso muito concluir isso espero que possa me ajudar agradeço muito

Comment: como faco para entrar